# Deleting or updating a document in lucene index

Tags: lucene

I have a simple lucene index, that contains some demo documents:

```
Title, Keywords, H1Tag
```

Now, I want to delete one of the documents in the index,
but from what I have read, I cannot depend on the docId, since it **might** change?

So how am I supposed to update/delete documents?

the only samples i find for delete/update, are based on Terms, like where the title equals what i want to delete, but what if i have 20 titles just the same?

Comment: To clarify: you can delete by DOMAIN-key (as in the key you assign to the document/entity yourself and might use in the rest of your backend.) Use in a query like denis suggests. However you cannot delete by the internal docid Lucene assigns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `Query` to DeleteDocuments also.

So,

`new QueryParser(...).Parse("+Title:... +H1Tag:.... +Keywords:...");`

can also be used to delete documents.

Another alternative would be to form your own boolen query

`BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery(); bq.Add(....);`

and passing that query to DeleteDocuments. But these are all you can do unless you store a field like `Key` and create your own unique key for each document(e.g, hashing).

Comment: only the last sentence in your answer gives me some kind of answer. 2 votes up... i wonder why.